# How to add SSH tab in Mobaxterm

Tags: mobaxterm

I am using Mobaxterm in my Windows 11

I used to get an SSH tab that shows all files on my university Linux server

For some reason now I do not get this tab anymore

I wonder if there is a way I can get that tab back

currently I am using FileZella to access files on the server but I want to be able to access these file through that SSH tab

How to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the Session icon in the top left corner of the MobaXterm client window (or use Ctrl-Shift-N). In the Session settings window, click the SSH icon in the top menu to select the SSH tab.